# Custom order processor not being run

Tags: 8, commerce

I have a custom order processor which currently just logs a debug message, so that I know that the order has been processed by it.

For whatever reason, my order processor is never run, I've checked against the [docs](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/en/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/order-refresh-and-process), looked at how other commerce modules does it (commerce_promotion and commerce_tax), none of them show that I am doing anything wrong.

**custom_commerce.services.yml**

```
services:
  custom_commerce.order_tax_processor:
    class: Drupal\custom_commerce\OrderTaxProcessor
    tads:
      - { name: commerce_order.order_processor, priority: 300 }
```

**OrderTaxProcessor.php class**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_commerce;

use Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_order\OrderProcessorInterface;

/**
 * Provides an order processor that adds tax to order if order has adjustments.
 * It does not affect order items.
 */
class OrderTaxProcessor implements OrderProcessorInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function process(OrderInterface $order) {
    \Drupal::logger('Custom commerce')->debug('Order processed check');
  }
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Other order processors seem to be running fine, but mine seems to be ignored/not run.

Running Drupal 8.5.3 and Commerce 2.6.0

Comment: I also have to write a custom  processor but I am getting this error... `'commerce_order.order_refresh' does not implement Drupal\commerce_o  
  rder\OrderProcessorInterface.                                                                                                               
                                  ` Can you please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what caused my problem, a silly typo...

Basically, in my *custom_commerce.services.yml* I had written `tads` instead of `tags`.

I fixed it and it's now running as it should.